# JSDoc not picking up on data child attribute type override

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've noticed a problem when working with a parent class that's extended by a child class.
Both classes have a 'data' attribute, in the parent class it's a generic 'Object' type and in the child class it is of type 'DogData'.

The parent's constructor is setting 'this.data = data' which should override the type to whatever the child's attribute's type is, but this is not happening.

Please find a small reproducible example below:

I hope I'm missing something and please don't hesitate to point it out if I am.

Thanks in advance

```
 * The animal base class
 * @class
 */
class Animal {
    /**
     * @param {number} id The ID of the animal
     * @param {Object} data The data of the animal
     */
    constructor (id, data) {
        this.id = id
        this.data = data
    }
}

/**
 * The Dog class
 * @class
 * @extends Animal
 */
class Dog extends Animal {

    /**
     * @typedef DogData
     * @property {number} age
     * @property {string} name
     */

    /**
     * @param {number} id The ID of the dog
     * @param {DogData} data The data of the dog
     */
    constructor (id, data) {
        super(id, data)
    }
}

const dog = new Dog(1, { age: 10, name: 'Foobar' })
dog.data. // Will only autocomplete if this.data is explicitly set inside the Dog constructor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the property before the constructor and use `@type` on it.

```js
class Dog extends Animal {

    /**
     * @typedef DogData
     * @property {number} age
     * @property {string} name
     */

    /**
     * @type {DogData}
     */
    data;

    /**
     * @param {number} id The ID of the dog
     * @param {DogData} data The data of the dog
     */
    constructor (id, data) {
        super(id, data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @asportnoy that workaround works. how would I go about methods with the same problem?